# python3 How do I click dropdown box using selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to click on dropbox using selenium on python3.
but I got an error msg.

```
 raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchWindowException: Message: Unable to find element on closed window
```

My code is below.

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#RegularCategory>div.pagination dl.dropdown dt a span").click()
```

and..code is ...
I want to click on "sort by" but I can't.
[image]

Comment: Is there in your code you are using `driver.quite()` or `driver.close()` somewhere before locating this element??

Comment: @SaurabhGaur
Of course, I am using driver.quite() at the end of the line

Answer (score 0):

You can use selenium's **select** Class and its APIs like select_by_index or select_by_value:
refer : [[http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html]](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html)

Comment: Please post your code so that we can really dig into the issue.

Comment: Not possible to get to the error wth just a line of code. Kindly share the related code and also the link along with the screenshot of the element which you are trying to locate.

Comment: I'm sorry that I don't understand what you talking about.
I already posted error message even code. but seems like you are trying to pull my leg. 
If you don't know...you don't need to reply!!

Comment: and plus...I found the answer...
I just add the windows focus and change the code that I posted.
driver.find_element_by_class_name('dropdown').click()
this is the what I found it...

Comment: Maybe I was missing out on something as I couldn't see the entire code. Anyways, good to know that you got it working.Cheers.